# Class 'Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Getting the following error in my Laravel installation:

```
FatalErrorException in Message.php line 17:
Class 'Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage' not found
```

It's comming from a Controller. And I've added:

```
use Mail;
```

This is the function that I'm executing:

```
public function testEmail($email)
{

    Mail::send('emails.test', ['email' => $email], function ($m) use ($email) {
        $m->from('mail@domain.com', 'example');
        $m->to($email, 'Test')->subject('example email');
    });
}
```

The test.php file exists aswell in the correct directory (views/emails/test.php).

The same function works just fine on another Laravel site.
Does anyone know why the class is not found? I thought I'd share the code anyways just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the SimpleMessage.php file, it was empty for some reason.